# EFI Shell: How to beep?

Tags: uefi, beep

in the EFi-Shell I want to make beep via the board speaker.
Can´t find any command or hint how to do so in the internet.

I´ve already tried as supposed in other discussions (not referring EFI-Shell):

echo '\a'

echo '\007'

I´m running the system on an Intel Atom Processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your hardware - whether there is a piezo speaker or not.

Look for the Beep utility in my [UEFI-Utilities-2018](https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2018) repository on Github for example C code and a compiled X64 binary (Beep.efi)

Comment: I have a piezo speaker. I´ve just tried the beep.efi file and it worked fine!! Thanks a lot! Nice utilities in your repo!!